# Build failed: "java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command.class"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to port an old android app to new devices. It works well from Android 5.x to 7.1, but it doesn't work in Android 4.x versions.

When I try to install it in an android device or in a emulator with Android 4.x the build always fails with the same exception:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command.class

I tried to search that "duplicate entry", but I was unable. I'm not sure what's the problem.

This is my build-gradle file:

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app-name"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 17
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
}
```

Comment: put your build.gradle file here

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line:

```
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'){
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

or
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar').
you are compiling same library two time as

```
'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

also have GoogleAnalyticsServices module.